# Stuck in single user mode after getting the log: systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB : executed by init(8) upon entering runlevel 1 (single)

Tags: linux, systemd, runlevel

I tried to enter in single user mode on Ubuntu 20.04 but after the login (or even without the login) it gave me the next log and then it stuck.

```
systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB : executed by init(8) upon entering runlevel 1 (single)..
```

Keyboard doesn't work and the cursor continues to blink like it waits an input. Any idea how to fix this?

EDIT:
I'm able to enter in multi-user mode and it works fine.
I noticed that in single-user it crashes when that log appear; before it I'm able to do the login and do some normal stuff.
I also tried to launch some script, but it were killed as that log appears. I don't know what happens, I'm on Odroidxu4 board using Ubuntu 20.04 kernel 5.4.

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more details. Does your system work in normal multi-user mode? What exactly did you do to enter single-user mode? If you want to enter single-user mode to solve a problem you noticed before, please write details about this problem.